# Error when unit testing child React component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, components, parent-child, enzyme

I have the following React Component:

```
import { getSeasonsalCode } from "./DiscountCodes.js";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Rating from "./Rating.js";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      rating: 0,
    };
  }

  setStarCount = (ct) => {
    this.setState({ rating: ct });
  };

  render() {
    var discount = getSeasonsalCode();
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{discount}</span>
        <Rating
          name="star_rating"
          size="2x"
          setStarCount={this.setStarCount}
        ></Rating>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Product);
```

And the following product.test.js. It tests the Rating child component, which requires a callback function from the parent component to set the rating value:

```
import Rating from "../src/Rating.js";
import Product from "../src/Product.js";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import expect from "expect";
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "../src/reducers/RootReducer.js";
import { createStore } from "redux";

describe("Product test suite", () => {
  it("set rating", () => {
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );

    const rf_wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Product />
      </Provider>
    ).dive();
    const rf_instance = rf_wrapper.instance();
    const sr_wrapper = shallow(
      <Rating
        name="star_rating"
        size="2x"
        setStarCount={rf_instance.setStarCount()}
      />
    );

    sr_wrapper.find("#star4").simulate("click");
    expect(rf_wrapper.state("starcount")).toEqual(4);
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get a TypeError saying discount is null or undefined at this line:

```
<span>{discount}</span>
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: What's `getSeasonsalCode`?

Comment: Why aren't you unit testing the `Rating` component alone as a unit? What is `getSeasonsalCode`` doing during the test execution?

Comment: Fixed the typo. getSeasonsalCode is the external method imported at the top. I do have a separate test suite for Rating alone. Here I want to test both parent and child as there is a callback func (setStarCount) that I want to test.

Comment: Ah, I see now, then you might not want to additionally render a separate `Rating` component in your test, find the one rendered in `rf_wrapper` to interact with. What is `getSeasonsalCode` supposed to be doing to set `discount`? Is `discount` being used somewhere else that requires it to not be null or undefined? React is perfectly capable of rendering either of these values.

Comment: Finding the Rating component rendered in rf_wrapper makes sense, but unfortunatelty the null error is thrown when Product component is being mounted, so I can't even access the instance. getSeasonsalCode returns a discount code base on consumer loyalty points, seasonality, etc. The only thing product component does with the discount code is display it.

Comment: why is the return outside the render method? does your component actually work when running the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to make a few changes to my original test suite and this is what worked for me:

```
import * as disc_module from '../src/DiscountCodes.js'

describe("Product test suite", () => {
  it("set rating", () => {
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );
    
    var disc_mock_obj = {
        "discount":{
            "expiration": new Date()
            "code": "OAABYT"
        }}

    jest
    .spyOn(disc_module, 'getSeasonsalCode')
    .mockImplementation(() => disc_mock_obj);

    //Got rid of call to dive() since it was not needed
    const rf_wrapper = mount( <Provider store={store}><Product></Product></Provider>);
    const prod_inst = rf_wrapper.find('Product');
    
    //Find clickable child component of Rating by id or any other unique attribute
    const child = rf_wrapper.find({'#star2'})   
    child.simulate('click')     
    expect(prod_inst.state('starcount')).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```